# Setting locationId in Asset

Tags: apex, unit-test, asset

I am working on test class of trigger of Asset.

I need to add location to the Asset object.

Have created the test class like below:

```
@isTest( seeAllData = false )
private class AssetTriggerTest {

    private static void insertAsset(){
        try{
            Asset assetObject;
            Location locationStandardObject;
            locationStandardObject = new Location();
            insert locationStandardObject;//Line 9

            assetObject = new Asset();
            assetObject.locationId = locationStandardObject.Id;//Line 12
            insert assetObject;
        }
        catch( Exception exceptionObject ){
            System.debug('Exception occurred=' 
                         + exceptionObject.getMessage()
                         +' Stack trace=' 
                         + exceptionObject.getStackTraceString()); 
            System.assert( false, 'Exception occurred=' 
                          + exceptionObject.getMessage()
                          +' Stack trace=' 
                          + exceptionObject.getStackTraceString()); 
        }
    }

    @isTest
    private static void testBeforeTrigger(){
        try{
            insertAsset();
        }
        catch( Exception exceptionObject ){
            System.debug('Exception occurred=' 
                         + exceptionObject.getMessage()
                         +' Stack trace=' 
                         + exceptionObject.getStackTraceString()); 
            System.assert( false, 'Exception occurred=' 
                          + exceptionObject.getMessage()
                          +' Stack trace=' 
                          + exceptionObject.getStackTraceString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Getting compilation error like below:

[image]

What I am missing here?

Comment: Have you actually tried to save your test class, or are those two "problems" showing up in the dev console before you save? Might be a false positive. Might be that you need to enable `Field Service Lightning` in this particular org.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is because there are two `Location` references known to the Apex Compiler (the [Location class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Location.htm) and the [Location SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_location.htm))

You need to code:

```
Schema.Location locationStandardObject;
locationStandardObject = new Schema.Location();
```

> “Location” in Salesforce can also refer to the geolocation compound field found on many standard objects. When referencing the Location object in your Apex code, always use Schema.Location instead of Location to prevent confusion with the standard Location compound field. If referencing both the Location object and the Location field in the same snippet, you can differentiate between the two by using System.Location for the field and Schema.Location for the object.